# create class with array

Tags: c++

I need to create an array of classes inside an other class.

Comment: Retagged as C++.  You can't create classes in C.  Also, you need to ask a question of some sort.  The only answer I can give to this is "That's nice; so what?"

Comment: Do you need an array of homogeneous or heterogeneous classes?

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
class Class {};

class OtherClass {
    Class array[1];
};
```

Comment: that's a very clean and elegant solution.

Comment: That is an array of objects, not an array of classes (Not that I have any idea what is an array of classes...)

Answer (score 3):

you should look at using std::vector, instead of carring about C-style arrays.

This is more the C++ way of coding, imagine a class containing an array of double:

```
class A
{
public:
    std::vector<double> m_doubles;
}
```

EDIT: so for an array of class, let's say class B:

```
class A
{
public:
    std::vector<B> m_bs;
}
```

EDIT2:

and like @cppanda suggests in the comments below, the implementation of std::vector is done in the [Standard C++ Library (also known as the STL)](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl). It's really worth the effort learning to use it intensively, a lot of things already done for you. ( like vector and many sorts of containers)

Comment: he wants an array of classes, double is not a classe. still the example is good, just replace <double> with <B> or something. 
@Manuel Marín Calero: best would be if you take a look at stl containers  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

Comment: @cppand okay I make an edit. to be more explicit. Nice remark.